# How to Kill or Abort Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew() in C#

Tags: multithreading, winforms, c#-4.0

I have situation where i have to Use `Task.Run` In my `ForEach` loop

**Requirement:**
I'm going to be forced to manually kill thread
I have button where i can start and stop this `Thread` or `Task.Run` in For loop.

**Problem**
My problem is when i start the Task.Run method Its running but when i try to stop with using `CancellationTokenSource` or `runningTaskThread.Abort();` it will not kill. its just stop when i start new Task.Run at that time it run with old thread so it become multiple thread every start process.

**Code:**

**Below is my code for start Thread**

```
 var messages = rootObject.MultiQData.Messages.Where(m => m.TimeStamp > DateTime.Now).OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp).ToList();
                                //Simulate MultiQ file in BackGroud 
                                if (messages.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                                    cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
                                    Task.Factory.StartNew(
                                        () =>
                                        {
                                            runningTaskThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
                                            messages.ForEach(
                                                m => SetUpTimer(m, rootObject.MultiQData.Connection.FleetNo));
                                        }, cancellationToken);
                                }
```

**For stop Task.Run**

```
 if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                else
                    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
```

I have also use `Thread` with `Thread.Abort` but it is not working

Please Help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution using `timer.Stop(),timer.Dispose()`. On creation of Thread i am calling  `SetUpTimer` and this SetupTimer i have created multiple timer.

So on call of stop thread i have dispose timer and its work for me

For reference see below code

```
private void SetUpTimer(Message message, string fleetNo)
        {
            var ts = new MessageTimer();

            var interval = (message.TimeStamp - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
            interval = interval <= 0 ? 100 : interval;

            ts.MessageWrapper = new MessageWrapper(message, fleetNo);
            ts.Interval = interval;
            ts.Elapsed += ts_Elapsed;
            ts.Start();

            //Add timer in to the lost for disposing timer at time of stop Simulation  
            lsTimers.Add(ts);
        }
```

> ```
>     private void StopTask()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             // Attempt to cancel the task politely
>             if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
>             {
>                 if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
>                     return;
>                 else
>                     cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
>             }
>
>             //Stop All Timer 
>             foreach (var timer in lsTimers)
>             {
>                 timer.Stop();
>                 timer.Dispose();
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             errorLogger.Error("Error while Stop simulation :", ex);
>         }
>
>     }
> ```